# Natural Join not working properly

Tags: ios, sql, sqlite, natural-join

I am doing sychronization in my iOS app. I have already a set of tables in my documents folder and I am downloading data from the server during synchronization into a new set of tables. I am comparing the count of individual tables and if they are the same, I am using natural join to check they are in fact the same. If they are the same, then my contents are up to date and I do not need to make any changes to my current set of tables, else I will get take the new set of tables and store the new data as my current tables.

The problem is that when I do natural join for certain tables, although I see the same information for both tables in SQLITEMANAGER, natural join returns incorrect answer. Not sure why. count_together is wrong, even though the values are the same.

This is how I implement my checking(just for illustration):

```
    singleton.table = YES;
    int count_table1 = 0;
    int count_table2 = 0;
    int count_together  = 0;

   NSMutableArray *arrayTables = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"DATA",@"TABLE",@"NUMBERS",nil];

    NSMutableArray *arrayTables2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"DATA2",@"TABLE2",@"NUMBERS2", nil];

    for(int i =0; i<[arrayTables count]; i++)
    {
        count_table1 = [databaseManager checkCountOfTable:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM %@",[arrayTables objectAtIndex:i]]];

        count_table2 = [databaseManager checkCountOfTable:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM %@",[arrayTables2 objectAtIndex:i]]];

        NSLog(@"Count of Table 1 is %i",count_table1);
        NSLog(@"Count of Table 2 is %i",count_table2);

        if (singleton.table == YES)
        {
            if(count_table1 != count_table2)
            {
                singleton.table = NO;
            }
            else
            {
                count_together = [databaseManager checkCountOfTable:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (%@ NATURAL JOIN %@)",[arrayTables objectAtIndex:i],[arrayTables2 objectAtIndex:i]]];

                NSLog(@"Count of Table 1 is %i",count_table1);
                NSLog(@"Count of Tables Together is %i",count_together);

                if (count_table1 == count_together)
                {
                    singleton.table = YES;
                }
                else
                {
                   singleton.table = NO;
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Need some guidance and am welcome to suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was there were some null columns in the tables. Hence the Natural JOIN on these tables do not work. Must ensure the tables do not have any null columns and the NATURAL JOIN will work fine.